# Should we always use Asynchronous JAX-RS resources For mobile backend?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I am building Mobile backend API using Java EE - JAX-RS 2.0 technology.

Since most of mobile client consumes are asynchronous http calls

**so my question is:** **Should I use asynchronous feature for all JAX-RS resources**? And the reason if not?

The below is the template Mobile Async API

```
@Path("/async_api")
public class AsyncResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/loadUsers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void loadUsers(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

        //TODO: ManagedExecutorService

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                List users = loadBigUsers();
                asyncResponse.resume(users);
            }

            private List loadBigUsers() {
                return null; // Return big list
            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: No. Asynchronous at the client doesn't imply asynchronous at the server, and *vice versa.* Make your own decision at each end independently.

Comment: You should use async on the server for long running tasks so it doesn't hold up the container threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JAX-RS the `@Suspend`annotation and `AsyncResponse` are needed only in certain typical scenarios. The first scenario was already identified in your code example. It is long running tasks. In this case the `AsyncResponse` can be used to execute long running code in a background thread. While this would not make sense at the first glance we need to think about how an application server / container handles its requests. Usually there is a pool of threads that accepts and handles client requests. If you implement expensive operations inline in your JAX-RS service methods one of the threads in the pool is blocked for the entire runtime. With the `AsyncResponse` the executor thread gets returned to the pool and other requests can be served in parallel.

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserRestService {

    @GET
    public void getAllUsers(@Suspend final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Users> users = UserDAO.loadAllUsers();
                asyncResponse.resume(users);
            }
        ) {}).start();
    }
}
```

The second application scenario for `AsyncResponse` is the often seen pattern of producer consumer patterns. Assuming you have a queue bound to the URL `https://yourservice.at/queue/next` then a `@GET` method can be used for a blocking `take()` on lets say a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. On the same URL you could bind a `@POST` method which adds data to the queue. In this case you would wrap up the functionality with the `take()` operation in an `AsyncResponse`.

```
@Path("/queue/next")
public class MessageQueueService {

    private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<AsyncResponse> suspendedResponses = new LinkedBlockingQueue<AsyncResponse>();

    @GET
    public void getNextMessage(@Suspend final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        MessageQueueService.suspendedResponses.put(asyncResponse);
    }

    @POST
    public void putNewMessage(final String message) throws InterruptedException {
        AsyncResponse asyncResponse = suspendedResponses.take(); // note how this could also block a thread
        asyncResponse.resume(message);
    }
}
```

From these explanations you can also see, that the JAX-RS `@Suspended` mechanism is used to create an asynchronous server side task. Whether or not the same request is also executed in an asynchronous manner on the client is a whole different story.

Comment: Thank you Matthias Steinbauer!